# Woocommerce disable products but not everywhere

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have some products that I don't want to be purchasable in traditionnal way.

They are comming in a "product box" that customers have to fill.

You can see here how it works :

[image: product box]

So all those product is 1€ products

and I tried to make them unpurchasable with this code :

```
function remove_add_to_cart_fruits_confits( $purchasable, $product ){
    if( $product->get_price() == 1 )
        $purchasable = false;
    return $purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'remove_add_to_cart_fruits_confits', 10, 2 );
```

But then we can not add them to the product box, it says "out of stock".

How can I make them purchasable only by adding them to this box ?

Comment: If you see the message "out of stock" it could depend on the stock of one of the products in the box. How is it managed? Do you use a plugin to do this? If a product is not available is it displayed in the choice options or is it hidden? It might not depend on the price.

Comment: those product are in stock, I even try with manual stock to 500. It's clearly when I add this code to make them unpurchasable that the out of stock message display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an effective solution. Below is the snippet:

```
// remove add to cart button conditionally
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_product_add_cart_button', 1 );
function remove_product_add_cart_button() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->get_price() == 1 ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
}
```

I have tested it and it works fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this tip. But this wont make a difference, the product with price 1$ will not be valid to go in box products ? Also, my box is a "product" post type, not a "box_product".

Comment: By inspecting the two product pages you will notice that this: confiserie-lilamand.com/produit/ballotins-a-composer-500g is a `box_product` product. This other instead confiserie-lilamand.com/produit/kiwi is a `simple` product. At this point another type of verification could be performed. Along with the price control, the type of product also occurs. Check out the code I've updated.

Comment: thanks for the update, same result as previously ! "out of stock" :( ( you can check live, i let it up ). ps : didn't know it was a product "box". Thanks for this info

Comment: I should find a solution where it's "only" if not on the box page that it disable those "simple" products. Isn't it possible to make something like "if(!is_type('product_box')) { } ?

Comment: If you try to temporarily remove the snippet from functions.php or plugin, do you still get the "out of stock" message?

Comment: no, as you can see previously without your or my snippet, it works perfectly. But then product is shoppable individualy

Comment: is possibile to do something like this : if(!is_type('product_box')) { } ?

Comment: I have updated the snippet. Can you try now?

Comment: No changes :/ how can i set $product->is_type('product_box') outside of my function ? Like "if on this page, don't execude this function" ? If I do : if (! $product->is_type( 'box_product' ) ) { add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'remove_add_to_cart_fruits_confits', 999, 2 ); } I have an error. I think this would be the solution.

Comment: I finally found the solution. The "is_purchasable" field cannot be changed because it is applied to all products, even to those children of other products (such as "Grouped", "Box Product", "Bundles", etc ..).

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO <3 this mean i have to change some other stuff, like display a specific message and hide price on those product, that was based on "is_purchasable", but doesn't mind IT WORKS !!!! SO MANY THANKS !!!

Comment: I'm happy for you. Remember that you can check the type of product displayed on the current page.

Comment: yep, I will do it !